# Restricting server.log file size (minecraft) in CentOS

Tags: centos, minecraft

I'm currently running a bukkit (minecraft) server which generates a server.log file with all the console messages / errors.

Every now and then I have a plugin (which i need) that crashes and can cause the server.log file size to increase dramatically. I've had it hit 32GB before which used all my disk space.

Is there a way to make it a rolling log (deletes old errors) or be able to limit the file size so it can't go above say 10MB. But the solution needs to not affect how the server runs so it doesn't throw an error when it can't write anymore.

Anyway of doing this with CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bukkit has built-in feature for this. Start the server using the `--log-limit=X` parameter, where X is the maximum log size in number of lines.